# paper_trail whodunnit only saving for child objects not parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, paper-trail-gem

I have the following method:

```
  def save_everything
    person.whodunnit("import_v2_file_id_#{file_id}") do
      person.save!
    end
  end
```

`person.save!` is saving an update to a person and a series of new child objects including phone and address records.

The whodunnit is getting set on the versions for the child objects but I don't understand why it's not getting set on the version for the person record :-/

So - I end up with the following:

```
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 21, item_type: "Phone", item_id: 7, event: "create", whodunnit: "import_v2_file_id_1", object: nil, created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:40">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 22, item_type: "Phone", item_id: 8, event: "create", whodunnit: "import_v2_file_id_1", object: nil, created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:40">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 23, item_type: "Phone", item_id: 9, event: "create", whodunnit: "import_v2_file_id_1", object: nil, created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:40">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 24, item_type: "Address", item_id: 7, event: "create", whodunnit: "import_v2_file_id_1", object: nil, created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:40">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 25, item_type: "Address", item_id: 8, event: "create", whodunnit: "import_v2_file_id_1", object: nil, created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:40">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 26, item_type: "Address", item_id: 9, event: "create", whodunnit: "import_v2_file_id_1", object: nil, created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:40">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 29, item_type: "Person", item_id: 1, event: "update", whodunnit: nil, object: "---\nid: 1\norganization_id: 1\nstate: \ntype: Individu...", created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:41">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 30, item_type: "Person", item_id: 1, event: "update", whodunnit: nil, object: "---\nid: 1\norganization_id: 1\nstate: \ntype: Individu...", created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:41">,
 #<PaperTrail::Version id: 31, item_type: "Person", item_id: 1, event: "update", whodunnit: nil, object: "---\nid: 1\norganization_id: 1\nstate: \ntype: Individu...", created_at: "2016-11-01 20:06:41">
```

Is there something blatantly off in my implementation here?

I'm using rails 3.2 and paper_trail 5.2.2

Comment: I'm realizing that I have a limit of 3 versions set - and perhaps the creation/addition of the associated records is causing some kind of callback :-/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there were callbacks associated with the creation of the child records and I had my versions limited to 3 ... so once the child records are created the relevant version had been deleted.